# .htaccess, many-to-one redirect, & exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set up a redirect for a domain in my .htaccess file, where all of the pages of the old domain get redirected to a single page on the new domain.

Additionally, I want to exclude a few pages on the old domain from this redirect.

So far, I've been able to get the many-to-one redirect to work, but the exceptions I have not figured out yet.

Here's my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/sample-page
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/landing-page/ [R=301,L]
```

I also replaced the second line with the follow to no avail:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sample-page
```

Any help with getting the exceptions to work would be appreciated.

Comment: The condition looks fine. Could it be that you are looking at a client side cached result?

Comment: I tried different computers & browsers, clearing the cache before checking, and the exempt links still redirect.

Comment: Then there has to be some other factor, maybe another redirection or rewriting rule in the actual http server's host configuration? What does your http server's error log file reveal?

Comment: There are a number of rewrite rules for redirects to external sites involving the old domain, which wanted to be excepted from the redirect to the new site. I found that, by copying my many-to-one redirect code along with the exceptions, and putting it after all the previous old-page-to-external-page redirects, the exceptions worked.